# Bootstrap/DataTable - How to detect page change and get number of the page

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

Hello i am using Bootstrap with DataTable - https://datatables.net

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document)
        .ready(function () {
            $('#datatable').dataTable({
                "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]]
            });
        });
</script>
```

I have no problem to run the table, but i do not know how can i bind an listener on the page change and alert the page number when a page is changed?

Can you please help me out with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document)
            .ready(function () {
              var table=$('#datatable').dataTable({
                    "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]]
                });
                $('#datatable').on( 'page.dt', function () {
                   var info = table.page.info();
                   alert(info.page+' of '+info.pages);  
                });  
            });
    </script>
```

It may help you.Please check it.